# graylog does not work out of the box

Tags: graylog

http://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/installation/docker.html

```
$ docker run --name mongo -d mongo:3
$ docker run --name elasticsearch \
    -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" \
    -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" \
    -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.5.4
$ docker run --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
    -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 \
    -e GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1:9000" \
    -d graylog/graylog:3.0
```

Then http://localhost:9000/ - 404.

Should it be working out of box?

Answer (score 2):

Should you like to have Graylog running on your local computer, please use the following:

```
$ docker run --name mongo -d mongo:3
$ docker run --name elasticsearch \
      -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" \
      -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" \
      -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.6.1
$ docker run --name graylog --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
      -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 \
      -e GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/" \
      -d graylog/graylog:3.0
```

Fix to the documentation is incoming. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Please start from checking logs. I think it is problem with environment for graylog docker.

IMHO, there is solution for your problem. Use GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9000, instead GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI.

Comment: Although checking logs is always a good thing to do; please note that the original question concerns a problem with  (documentation from)  deprecated Graylog version 3, released  roughly 4 years ago in 2019. Many (major) updates have been released since, as hinted at already by the [other answer](https://serverfault.com/a/956675/984089) from what appears somebody from Graylog.

Comment: Yes, but lately I have upgraded from graylog 2.4, so wanted to share :)